# Entity framework mapping exception

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am learning Entity Framework so I createda simple model with two tables , add appropiate classes and I am trying to write a simple repo, but the application crushes in my repo :(

MyEntityPOCO is the name of my console App project :)

link to database vizualisation http://wstaw.org/w/LrL/

This is the code of my repo

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Data.Objects;

    namespace MyEntityPOCO
    {
         public class Entities : ObjectContext
         {
              private ObjectSet _contacts;
              private ObjectSet _addresses;

              public Entities()
                   : base("name=MyEntities", "MyEntities")
              {
                   _contacts = CreateObjectSet();
                   _addresses = CreateObjectSet();
              }

              public ObjectSet Contacts
              { get { return _contacts; } }


              public ObjectSet Addresses
              { get { return _addresses; } }

         }

    }
```

This is the detail about the exception.

```
    {"Mapping and metadata information could not
     be found for EntityType 'MyEntityPOCO.Contact'."}
```

This is Contact

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Collections;

        namespace MyEntityPOCO
        {
             public class Contact
             {
                  public int ContactID { get; set; }
                  public string FirstName { get; set; }
                  public string LastName { get; set; }
                  public ICollection Addresses { get; set; }
             }
        }
```

Address

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;

    namespace MyEntityPOCO
    {
         public class Address
         {

              public int AddressID { get; set; }
              public string Street { get; set; }
              public string City { get; set; }
         }
    }
```

This my App.Config

This is connection string from model properties

```
    metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string="data source=COMPAL\COMPALSERWER;initial catalog=MyBase1;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework"
```

this is connection string from server explorer

```
    Data Source=COMPAL\COMPALSERWER;Initial Catalog=MyBase1;Integrated Security=True
```

and provider from server explorer

```
.NET Framework Data Provider for SQL Server
```

Comment: Where is your edmx? How did the above get generated? By hand or via the edmx generator?

Comment: This is my edmx file.
I generated this code by hand.

Comment: whis is link to jpeg with edmx http://wstaw.org/w/LrL/

Comment: It sounds like your metadata connection string is not set up correctly. Need to see more code to be sure (like your app.config connection string for MyEntities).

Answer (score 0):

Your Contact's 'Addresses' is a collection of ...? You must declare it is a collection of Address objects for EF to do the mapping correctly.

```
public class Contact
{
    public int ContactID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
}
```